# "package" causing a class not found error when using JavaNativeInterface

Tags: java, c++

this is my first ever question so I am sorry if I cannot explain my problem clearly. I am learning Java Native Interface. And I am running into a very weird error when I use the package keyword. My tests run fine without this keyword. I am using Windows.
Below is an example of my problem.
In a folder 'Test', I create an AddNumbers.java file

```
package Test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddNumbers {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("addNumbers");;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddNumbers adder = new AddNumbers();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ENTER INTEGER 1: ");
        int i1 = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ENTER INTEGER 2: ");
        int i2 = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("THE SUM IS: " + adder.Add_Numbers(i1, i2));
    }
    private native int Add_Numbers(int i1, int i2);
}
```

Then in powershell, I run  `javac -h . AddNumbers.java` and this gives me AddNumbers.class and
AddNumbers.h. Below is AddNumbers.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class AddNumbers */

#ifndef _Included_AddNumbers
#define _Included_AddNumbers
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_AddNumbers_Add_1Numbers
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I write a AddNumbers.cpp file:

```
#include "AddNumbers.h"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_AddNumbers_Add_1Numbers
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint first, jint second){
      return first + second;
  }
```

Then I run `` g++ -c -IC:\Program` Files\Java\jdk-17\include AddNumbers.cpp -o AddNumbers.o `` followed by  `g++ -shared -o addNumbers.dll AddNumbers.o` to get the .dll file. But now that I do `java AddNumbers` it gives me a class not found error. I have even tried with full qualified name of classes that is `java Test.AddNumbers` in this case I hope. The only difference is that if I remove package from AddNumbers.java the program works. What am I missing?

Edit: i wasn't going back to previous directory before calling java

Answer (score 1):

The header file needs to be updated when you move `AddNumbers` into a package. If you run `javac -h` on `AddNumbers.java` when it contains the `package Test;` line, the header file will declare `Java_Test_AddNumbers_Add_1Numbers` instead of `Java_AddNumbers_Add_1Numbers`. This should make sense: the native function name contains the full name of the Java class and moving a class into different package changes its full name, so the native function name changes when you move class into a package. The error you see is because Java can't match the native implementation to the class method if the names are wrong.

Regenerate the header file by running `javac -h` again and update the implementation file to match the new function name.